# Pointers in C: changes inside a function

Tags: c

I ran into this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* p1, int* p2) 
{
   p1 = p2;
   *p1 = *p2 + 1; 
}

void bar(int** p1, int** p2) 
{
  p1 = p2;
  *p1 = *p2 + 1;
  **p1 = **p2 + 2;
}

void main (void) 
{
  int n[] = {1,2,3};
  int m[] = {4,5,6};
  int *p1 = n;
  int *p2 = m;

  foo(p1,p2);
  bar(&p1,&p2);
  printf("%d %d\n",*p1,*p2);
}
```

I thought the output will be [1,5] while it's [1,7].
Can someone explain the reason?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post the code as a text in the Question body, not as a link.

Comment: `void main(void)` has undefined behaviour in C standard, unless it is an implementation-defined way of prototyping `main`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: I updated the code. my question was about the pointer's behaviour.

Comment: @EladPardilov Antti's comment is not relevant for this question. I rollbacked the question. If your implementation defines void main(void) as main, then that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to distinguish `p1` and `p2` within main and `p1`, `p2` within the functions, which are not the same. So I will rename the parameters of foo and bar into `fp1`, `fp2`, `bp1`, `fp2` to be able to differentiate more clearly. This won't change anything in behaviour.

So main first calls `foo(p1, p2);`. `fp1` and `fp2` then are copies of the pointers `p1` and `p2`. Within foo:

1. `fp1 = fp2;` fp2 is assigned to fp1. So both fp1 and fp2 hold the address of the array p2 was assigned to (i. e. `m` within main).
2. `*p1 = *p2 + 1;` as both p1 and p2 hold the address of m (or m[0], which is the same for arrays), m[0] is incremented (was 4, now is 5).

Then calling `bar(&p1, &p2);`. So `bp1` and `bp2` now hold the addresses of the two pointers `p1` and `p2` within main (i. e. you can modify p1 and p2 themselves from within bar!), which is going to happen then, too:

1. `bp1 = bp2;` again both pointers hold the same address, which is the one of p2 within main (still with address of m[0]).
2. `*bp1 = *bp2 + 1;` as both bp1 and bp2 point to the same pointer, results in incrementing this pointer, so effectively increments p2, now pointing to m[1].
3. `**bp1 = **bp2 + 2;` bp1 and bp2 both point to p2, which points to m[1]. So m[1] is incremented by 2 (m[1] was 5, now is 7!).

Finally printing the values. Remember, p2 itself was modified within bar, now pointing to m[1], which again was modified to 7, so the result you did not expect...